# max value with zipped arrays in forloop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
women= [158, 166, 150, 158, 152, 160, 172, 159, 158, 162]
men= [168, 172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185]



for men, women in zip(men, women):

    print (men, women, abs(men-women))
```

In arrays are  height values of men and women.
How can i get the  biggest difference in absolute value?

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
print (max(abs(man-woman) for man, woman in zip(men, women)))
```

Comment: Or a generator expression even.

Comment: This is a Python 3 question, so there must be `()` around the argument of `print`

Comment: @cfi thus my comment.

Comment: @wwii: Ah. Got the meaning all wrong, then ;) I thought you meant it as a suggestion for further improvement. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a key to max:

```
women= [158, 166, 150, 158, 152, 160, 172, 159, 158, 162]
men= [168, 172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185]

best = (max(zip(men,women),key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1])))
print ("Best pair are {}, {}\ndifference = {}".format(best[0],best[1], abs(best[0]-best[1])))
Best pair are 181, 150
difference = 31
```

`lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1])` compares gets the absolute difference between the elements in each tuple.

If you want a loop:

```
best_abs = None
for m, w in zip(men, women):
    if best_abs is None or abs(m-w) > best_abs:
        best_abs = abs(m-w)
        best_pair = m,w
print ("Best pair are {}, {}\ndifference = {}".format(best_pair[0],best_pair[1], best_abs))
Best pair are 181, 150
difference = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sort,

```
>>> sorted(zip(men,women), key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1]))[-1]
(181, 150)


>>> sorted(zip(men,women), key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1]),reverse=True)[0]
(181, 150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using heapq:

```
heapq.nlargest(1, (((a - b), a, b) for a, b in zip(men, women)))
```

Output:

```
[(31, 181, 150)]
```

For the entire lists:

```
heapq.nlargest(10, (((a - b), a, b) for a, b in zip(men, women)))
```

Output:

```
[(31, 181, 150), (23, 185, 162), (20, 172, 152), (14, 174, 160), (11, 169, 158), (10, 169, 159), (10, 168, 158), (8, 166, 158), (6, 172, 166), (-7, 165, 172)]
```